# Nextjs - Can you bypass the next.config.js basePath value for individual pages?

Tags: next.js, routes, url-routing

I've got what is probably a pretty simple question here. In our codebase, nearly all of the pages in our application branch off of a `/app` base path, so we've defined the attribute as such in our `next.config.js` file:

```
const moduleExports = {
  basePath: '/app',
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

But, for a new feature, we want the page to live on a separate on a separate path - `domain.com/a/[slug]` rather than `domain.com/app/a/[slug]`. Is there a way I can exclude this particular page from the `basePath` attribute defined in `next.config.js`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude pages from the `basePath` as far as I know, however, there are some work arounds you can use to achieve a similar result:

- **Method 1** - You could use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in your `next.config.js`, with the `:path*` to keep the functionality of your dynamic route:

```js
const moduleExports = {
  basePath: '/app',
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/a/:path*',
        destination: '/app/a/:path*',
      },
    ]
  },
};
```

- **Method 2** - Don't use the `basePath` property. This won't work if you're using [multi zones](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones) or in a monorepo with turborepo. Instead, you could create  a folder `app`, and put all of your app in there apart from your `/a/[slug]` route:

```
pages/
├─ a/
│  ├─ [slug]
├─ app/
├─ rest of your app
```